# generating a local link/path to PDF File for direct access

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to write a programm for Data extraction from PDF in Python (Excel Macro could be an option) . 
At first at want to select a text or a position in a pdf file and generate a local path/link to that file in that position. This link will be copied to an excel cell. When I click on the link the PDF document should open on the specified coordinates of the previously selected text.

I know the question is very broad. I'm an enthusiast beginner and need a nudge in the right direction and to know if it is  possible.

How can I get the path of the active pdf file in the desktop? and the coordinate of the selected text? I could give these automatically as parameters then to my programm.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of ways to do this, I would say look into the Slate --> https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slate , or http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html

And yes it's quite easy , also look into `pyPdf`

```
import pyPdf

def getPDFContent(path):
    content = ""
    # Load PDF into pyPDF
    pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(file(path, "rb"))
    # Iterate pages
    for i in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
        # Extract text from page and add to content
        content += pdf.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
    # Collapse whitespace
    content = " ".join(content.replace("\xa0", " ").strip().split())
    return content

print getPDFContent("test.pdf")
```

Comment: Thank you!I think the function gives back the content of the PDF file specified in the "path" right? 

I would like the Path to be a variable not fix. Is that possible? I also need the possition of a selected text like (Line, letter position: 500, 50) for example

Comment: yes, it basically loads up the whole file onto the object `pdf` , this is a bit outdated though, try `Slate`.

Comment: sorry one last question, the file should open normally in adobe reader and not just be printed in the command box. POssible?

Comment: actually the above is just printing the content of PDF on console, You can either redirect the output to a .pdf file and open it via adobe reader.